# how can i alternate row class after api data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried everything i know and can't get an alterate tablerow class to work , without having all the rows duplicated or having a bunch of dummy rows inserted

Here is what i have

```
<script>
fetch("https://www63.myfantasyleague.com/2021/export?TYPE=league&L=43570&JSON=1").then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data.league.franchises.franchise);
        if (data.league.franchises.franchise.length > 0) {
          var temp = "";
          temp += "<table id='league_emails'>";
          temp += "<tbody>";
          temp += "<tr><th>Franchise</th><th>Owner Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
          data.league.franchises.franchise.forEach((itemData) => {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.league.franchises.franchise.length; i++) {
              if (i % 2)
                temp += '<tr class="eventablerow">';
              else
                temp += '<tr class="oddtablerow">';

            }

            temp += "<td>" + itemData.name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.owner_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.email + "</td>";

          });
          temp += "</tbody>";
          temp += "</table>";
          document.getElementsByClassName('commish_league_safe')[0].innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
</script>
<div class="commish_league_safe"></div>
```

The issue lays here and i have tried a dozen things and wrapped it different ways

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.league.franchises.franchise.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2)
        temp += '<tr class="eventablerow">';
    else
        temp += '<tr class="oddtablerow">';

}
```

Comment: You're only adding row tags in your for-loop.  You need to add the data and then close that row before the next time through the loop.

Comment: please show example , i feel like i've tried everything

Comment: Try to closing tr
data.league.franchises.franchise.forEach((itemData) => {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.league.franchises.franchise.length; i++) {
              if (i % 2)
                temp += '<tr class="eventablerow">';
              else
                temp += '<tr class="oddtablerow">';

            }

            temp += "<td>" + itemData.name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.owner_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.email + "</td>";
           temp+="</tr>";
          });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<script>
fetch(https://www63.myfantasyleague.com/2021/export?TYPE=league&L=43570&JSON=1).then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data.league.franchises.franchise);
        if (data.league.franchises.franchise.length > 0) {
          var temp = "";
          temp += "<table id='league_emails'>";
          temp += "<tbody>";
          temp += "<tr><th>Franchise</th><th>Owner Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
          data.league.franchises.franchise.forEach((itemData,i) => {

            /* for (var i = 0; i < data.league.franchises.franchise.length; i++) { */
              if (i % 2)
                temp += '<tr class="eventablerow">';
              else
                temp += '<tr class="oddtablerow">';

            /* } */

            temp += "<td>" + itemData.name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.owner_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.email + "</td>";
            temp += "</tr>";

          });
          temp += "</tbody>";
          temp += "</table>";
          document.getElementsByClassName('commish_league_safe')[0].innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
</script>
<div class="commish_league_safe"></div>
```

Just before ending the loop close the tr tag.
temp += "" + itemData.email + ""; after this line just add closing tag to append that to temp variable.

Comment: Gives me 100s of dummy table rows so I think it’s something else

Comment: @MShack kindly check this fiddle link for the output
https://jsfiddle.net/prathap937/Lxvwpq7g/
.Since owner name and email address is not available in the api response causing undefined in those columns

Comment: i update the url to prove the API key so those values are shown. Regardless it still shows a lot of extra rows  https://jsfiddle.net/hLu7wq65/4/  . Inspect the element and see all the extra rows

Comment: updated your fiddle and added some css to show all the extra rows that display  https://jsfiddle.net/hLu7wq65/4/

Comment: Changed logic, kindly check this link and see if it match with your requirements https://jsfiddle.net/prathap937/Lxvwpq7g/4/

Comment: oh jeesh , how simple and i couldn't figure that out with all i tried , place the "i" in initial statement did the trick. Thank you very much for your time